# Настройка ПЛАВНОЙ анимации

Tags: css

Как настроить анимацию так, чтобы элементы плавно плыли по течению. Думаю проблема в процентный значениях между кадрами. Вот песок: https://jsfiddle.net/8awkpysn/1/ И собственно код.

```css
.q1{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
  background:black;
  animation: c1 5s linear infinite; 
}
.q2{
  position:absolute;
  left:110px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:black;
  animation: c2 5s linear infinite;
}
 
@keyframes c1 {
   15%{
       left:-252px;
   }
   15.1%{
        left:450px;
   }
 }
@keyframes c2 {
   15%{
       left:-252px;
   }
   15.1%{
        left:560px;
   }
   to{
       left:110px;
   }
}
```

```html
<p class="q1"></p>
<p class="q2"></p>
```

Comment: Не вижу проблемы, у меня элементы плавно текут влево

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перемещать блоки на одинаковое расстояние чтобы у них была одинаковая скорость.

```
.q1{
  position:absolute;
  left: 702px;
  width:100px;
  height:80px;
  background:black;
  animation: c1 5s linear infinite; 
}
.q2{
  position:absolute;
  left: 702px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:black;
  animation: c2 5s linear infinite .7s;
}

@keyframes c1 {
   0%{
       left: 702px
   }
   100%{
        left: -100px
   }
 }
@keyframes c2 {
   0%{
       left: 702px
   }
   100%{
        left: -100px
   }

}
```

Comment: Забыл, не могу сделать так чтобы первый после того как исчезал появлялся в конце, как слайлер

Comment: обновил код, блоки стартуют с одной позиции, проходят одинаковое расстояние чтоб скорость была одинаковой, второй стартует с задержкой так происходит разрыв между блоками, как то так.

Comment: Спасибо! идеально.

Comment: Подобные слайдеры на JS делают? просто на чистом CSS я голову сломал пока расстояние и скорость настроил

Comment: Это мало чем слайдер напоминает, просто анимация слайдеры обычно по другому устроены, вот к примеру хороший https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html

Comment: Как я понял по хорошему это на чистом CSS не делается, слайдеры, модельные окна всплывающие меню и т.д.

Comment: Ну почему же, все зависит от целей) если работает так как тебе надо и работает во всех браузерах в которых надо чтоб работало, тогда можно и без js, но я думаю самому анимацию есть смысл писать если она необычная а если задача тривиальная то легче скачать слайдер или воспользоваться готовым набором типа этого https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ там есть отдельная анимация на появление слайда и на исчезновение то есть берешь и используешь) и не пишешь с нуля.

Comment: Никогда не анимировать элементы через absolute - только через transform.